# Escape comma in TFS work item query

Tags: tfs

I need to query for work items assigned to one of multiple people, but the comma in the names seems to make this query not work.

In the image below, I want to query for work items assigned to "Smith, John" and "Doe, John"

Is there a way to do this without the use of many and/or lines? I want to do this for like 4-7 people in different queries. Can I escape the comma?

[image: team foundation work item query]

Comment: Why do you have commas in the users name?

Comment: not sure, my admin has  'last, first' formatting

Comment: Dear me... That is not a plesent configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the In operator and give it a delimited list as you have above. The delimited however is region specific. My delimited is ", " but yours maybe different.

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs_top_tip_1_w.html

You can also, as you are querying for a list of users use the "In Group" lookup and use a TFS security group or AD group.

Update: As your AD guys have done a silly thing and put a comma in the users names (who does that!) you may have to quote or double-quote each name in the list.

Comment: thanks, I think the link shows that single or double quotes doesn't work. per the link - when using single quotes around the names "it parses on the commas first which is not what you wanted at all." so I guess I would need to change usernames or regional settings

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to include multiple Or statements in an 'And Block', OR you can create a TFS group that includes the people you want included in the 'Assigned To' field and use that in a single And clause.